# How do I show that $u_x$, $u_y$, $u_{xx}$, $u_{yy}$ and $u_{xy}$ are also solution for the pde $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Title says it all. Let $u$ satisfy the patial differntial equation $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$(elliptic in linear 2nd order pde). How do I show that $u_x$, $u_y$, $u_{xx}$, $u_{yy}$ and $u_{xy}$ are also solution? I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: By Schwarz, for example $$ (u_x)_{yy} = u_{xyy} = u_{yyx} = (u_{yy})_x $$

Comment: Typo ... corrected, I referred to the "symmetry of higher derivatives" theorem by Hermann Schwarz.